# Orchard CMS Part placement

Tags: c#, html, .net, content-management-system, orchardcms

I've been struggling with placing specific parts of a Content item in a view. My question is how do I define a `cshtml` view/shape for a content item for which I can place each part where I want. Consider the following content item:

```
item
  - Text field
  - Media field
```

And the following

```
<div class="my text">
    @Model.TextField1
    <div class="media-item">
        @Model.MediaField
    </div>
</div>
<p> Some text or stuf here or anyehere</p>
```

I can't seem to find any example of that. It should be a basic view for a content with assigned objects to each part of that content but I am finding it impossible to implement (btw I don't want to use layouts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a working alternate, say Content-MyContentType.cshtml, you can do the following:

```
<div class="my text">
    @Display(Model.TextFields)
    <div class="media-item">
        @Display(Model.Media)
    </div>
</div>
<p> Some text or stuf here or anyehere</p>
```

And then you can do in your placement.info:

```
<Match ContentType="MyContentType">
    <Place Fields_Common_Text="TextFields" />
    <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="Media" />
</Match>
```

**Note**

I am not sure what type of fields your textfields and/or your media is, so you might need to change the Fields_Common_Text and Fields_MediaLibraryPicker to match the types of your fields.

Comment: I tried using alternates however all parts are in `@Model.Content.Items` which is an array. There isn't a way to choose which content part to render at an exact place. But your solution seems fantastic I didn't know I can do that in the placement.info (adding unrecognized zones)

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't include a lot of detail to really determine what your issue is, but here area a few suggestions:

Make sure your Placement.info file is up to date for the DisplayType you are trying to use, here is an example from one of mine:

```
<Placement>
<Place Parts_McrfProfile_Edit="Content:3"/>
<Place Parts_McrfProfile_Summary="Content:6"/>
<Place Parts_McrfProfileList_Edit="Content:3"/>
<Place Parts_McrfProfileList_Summary="Content:6"/>
<Place Parts_McfProfile_List="Content:6"/>

<Match DisplayType="Detail">
<!-- hide summary, show full content, for Detail -->
<Place Parts_McrfProfile_Summary="-"
       Parts_McrfProfileList_Summary="-"
       Parts_McfProfile_List="-"
       Parts_McrfProfile="Content:6"
       Parts_McrfProfileList="Content:6"
       />
<Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
</Match>

<Match DisplayType="Summary">
<Place Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary="-"/>

</Match>

<Match DisplayType="ListView">
   <Place Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary="-"
       Parts_McrfProfile_Summary="-"
       Parts_McrfProfileList_Summary="-"
       Parts_McrfProfile="-"
       Parts_McrfProfileList="-"
       Parts_McrfProfile_List="Content:6"/>
  </Match>
</Placement>
```

Then in your display driver, make sure you are building the correct display types, here is an example using a few:

```
    protected override DriverResult Display(
    McrfProfilePart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return Combined(
       ContentShape("Parts_McrfProfile",
                         () =>
                         {
                             part.ProfileDetail = _profileService.GetProfileDetail(part.ProfileId);

                             McrfProfileDetailViewModel profileDetailViewModel = new McrfProfileDetailViewModel();

                             profileDetailViewModel.ProfileDetail = part.ProfileDetail;

                             return shapeHelper.Parts_McrfProfile(ProfileDetail: profileDetailViewModel);
                          }),
        ContentShape("Parts_McrfProfile_List",
                         () =>
                         {
                             return shapeHelper.Parts_McrfProfile_List(ProfileRecord: part);
                         }),
        ContentShape("Parts_McrfProfile_Summary",
                         () =>
                         {
                             McrfProfileSummaryViewModel profileSummaryViewModel = new McrfProfileSummaryViewModel();

                             List<int> profileID = new List<int>() { part.ProfileId };

                             var summary = _profileService.GetProfileSummaryList(profileID).Where(e => e.ProfileID == part.ProfileId).First();

                             profileSummaryViewModel.JobTitle = summary.JobTitle;
                             profileSummaryViewModel.Name = summary.Name;
                             profileSummaryViewModel.ProfileImage = summary.ProfileImage;
                             profileSummaryViewModel.ProfileID = summary.ProfileID;

                             return shapeHelper.Parts_McrfProfile_Summary(ProfileRecord: profileSummaryViewModel);
                         }));

    }
```

Finally, if you have done these correctly and are getting valid data back from your service (or by whatever means you are getting data), you should be able to use your view as follows:

```
@{
Mcrf.Profiles.ViewModels.McrfProfileDetailViewModel part =   Model.ProfileDetail;
Style.Include("profile-styles.css?v=1.0").AtHead();
Style.Include("bootstrap.css?v=1.0").AtHead();
}

@if (Model != null && part.ProfileDetail != null)
{
<div>
    <div >
        <div class="profileImgDiv">
            @if (Model != null && part != null)
            {
                if (part.ProfileDetail.ProfileImage == null)
                {
                    <img class="profile-img" src="~/Modules/Mcrf.Profiles/Content/Images/noProfilePictureImage.jpg" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <img class="profile-img" src="@Url.Content(part.ProfileDetail.ProfileImage)" />
                }
            }
        </div>
```

etc, etc, etc,

I hope this helps,

Roka